# Adding a custom input field in formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I can't figure out, or find any solutions to a very simple question:
"How can I define my own input field in formtastic?"

This is what I got:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @someFantasticVariable, :url => "/someFantasticUrl.html" do |f|%>  
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :something_else_id, :required => true , :as => :select, :collection   => SomethingElse.find(:all), :label =>"The something else"%>
        <%= f.input :fantastic_max_cost, :label => "Budget (max cost)"%>  
    <%end%>


    <%= f.buttons do%>
        <%= f.commit_button :button_html => { :class => "primary", :disable_with =>     'Processing...', :id => "commitButton"}%>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Now..

I want to have a very simple thing. I want to ad a field that is not part of the model. I want to have a date field that I can use to calculate some stuff in my controller. So I want to do this:

```
<%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :something_else_id, :required => true , :as => :select, :collection   => SomethingElse.find(:all), :label =>"The something else"%>
    <%= f.input :fantastic_max_cost, :label => "Budget (max cost)"%>  
    <%= f.input :start_date, :as => :date , :label => "Start date"%>
<%end%>
```

But apparetly I'm not allowed, and I can't find any way to do this through my thrusted googling. Any help / ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have some attribute that is not part of your model, then a getter and a setter should exist on the model:

```
def start_date
end

def start_date=(arg)
end
```

Then you can calculate your staff on a controller or whatever you want:

```
...
puts params[:somefantasticvariable][:start_date]
...
```

But this is a quick formtastic hack, you should find some better way, like non-formtastic input with some css etc.

Comment: What I really want is just an extra parameter when I send the form. But I will see if this will do the trick.

Comment: It worked :) But it feels like a hack though. Would be nice if formtastic had an easy way to add fields that is not part of the model. As I said. I only need the parameter when I send the form, so it does not really belong in the model. But this works for now. Thanks :)

Comment: "If you have some attribute that is not part of your model, then a getter and a setter should exist on the model" Huh?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby provides a database-less construct called an `attr_accessor`. It is the equivalent of writing setter and getter methods. Formtastic will see this attribute similar to a database-backed attribute.

In your `@someFantasticVariable` model:

```
attr_accessor :start_date
```

If using attr_accessible in your `@someFantasticVariable` model, be sure to add the `start_date` variable there too:

```
attr_accessible :start_date
```

Because the attribute is type-less, Formtastic cannot derive the HTML input field to use. You will need to manually set the input type using `:as`. For your example:

```
<%= f.input :start_date, :as => :date_select %>
```

Cite:

- http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor
- https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#the-available-inputs